# Java c3p0 apparent deadlock - SQL Server stuck?

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, deadlock, c3p0

We have a java (1.6.x) web application backed by a **SQL Server 2008 R2** database (Hibernate 3 ORM - **C3P0 0.9.2.1**) and several times usually when the system is under heavy load we see these lines in our logs and the customers complain about slowness.

```
2016-03-01 10:11:27,372 WARN C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1bqoobh9fc5bldvr10ww5|13e9d0cc]-AdminTaskTimer com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner - com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@4c0bee48 -- APPARENT DEADLOCK!!! Creating emergency threads for unassigned pending tasks!
2016-03-01 10:11:27,372 WARN C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1bqoobh9fc5bldvr10ww5|13e9d0cc]-AdminTaskTimer com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner - com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@4c0bee48 -- APPARENT DEADLOCK!!! Complete Status: 
    Managed Threads: 20
    Active Threads: 20
    Active Tasks: 
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$StatementDestructionManager$1UncheckedStatementCloseTask@69de8a09
            on thread: C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1bqoobh9fc5bldvr10ww5|13e9d0cc]-HelperThread-#11
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$StatementDestructionManager$1UncheckedStatementCloseTask@11388b2c
            on thread: C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1bqoobh9fc5bldvr10ww5|13e9d0cc]-HelperThread-#3
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$StatementDestructionManager$1UncheckedStatementCloseTask@1738fe89
            on thread: C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1bqoobh9fc5bldvr10ww5|13e9d0cc]-HelperThread-#1
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$StatementDestructionManager$1UncheckedStatementCloseTask@1ecee048
            on thread: C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1bqoobh9fc5bldvr10ww5|13e9d0cc]-HelperThread-#13
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$StatementDestructionManager$1UncheckedStatementCloseTask@1fe6a6c5
            on thread: C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1bqoobh9fc5bldvr10ww5|13e9d0cc]-HelperThread-#2
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$StatementDestructionManager$1UncheckedStatementCloseTask@5fcedfdf
            on thread: C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1bqoobh9fc5bldvr10ww5|13e9d0cc]-HelperThread-#10
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$StatementDestructionManager$1UncheckedStatementCloseTask@6cbda9d
            on thread: C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1bqoobh9fc5bldvr10ww5|13e9d0cc]-HelperThread-#0
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$StatementDestructionManager$1UncheckedStatementCloseTask@317d7ce7
            on thread: C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1bqoobh9fc5bldvr10ww5|13e9d0cc]-HelperThread-#4
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$StatementDestructionManager$1UncheckedStatementCloseTask@25933b13
            on thread: C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1bqoobh9fc5bldvr10ww5|13e9d0cc]-HelperThread-#12
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$StatementDestructionManager$1UncheckedStatementCloseTask@650b6faa
            on thread: C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1bqoobh9fc5bldvr10ww5|13e9d0cc]-HelperThread-#5
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$StatementDestructionManager$1UncheckedStatementCloseTask@51d035b9
            on thread: C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1bqoobh9fc5bldvr10ww5|13e9d0cc]-HelperThread-#17
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$StatementDestructionManager$1UncheckedStatementCloseTask@3c772ea5
            on thread: C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1bqoobh9fc5bldvr10ww5|13e9d0cc]-HelperThread-#9
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$StatementDestructionManager$1UncheckedStatementCloseTask@349771a6
            on thread: C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1bqoobh9fc5bldvr10ww5|13e9d0cc]-HelperThread-#14
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$StatementDestructionManager$1UncheckedStatementCloseTask@42a66443
            on thread: C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1bqoobh9fc5bldvr10ww5|13e9d0cc]-HelperThread-#15
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$StatementDestructionManager$1UncheckedStatementCloseTask@3a008ce4
            on thread: C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1bqoobh9fc5bldvr10ww5|13e9d0cc]-HelperThread-#7
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$StatementDestructionManager$1UncheckedStatementCloseTask@7a21ea7b
            on thread: C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1bqoobh9fc5bldvr10ww5|13e9d0cc]-HelperThread-#16
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$StatementDestructionManager$1UncheckedStatementCloseTask@48a96fe1
            on thread: C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1bqoobh9fc5bldvr10ww5|13e9d0cc]-HelperThread-#6
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$StatementDestructionManager$1UncheckedStatementCloseTask@6bf0420b
            on thread: C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1bqoobh9fc5bldvr10ww5|13e9d0cc]-HelperThread-#18
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$StatementDestructionManager$1UncheckedStatementCloseTask@6a801789
            on thread: C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1bqoobh9fc5bldvr10ww5|13e9d0cc]-HelperThread-#19
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$StatementDestructionManager$1UncheckedStatementCloseTask@7f8959fe
            on thread: C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1bqoobh9fc5bldvr10ww5|13e9d0cc]-HelperThread-#8
    Pending Tasks: 
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StmtAcquireTask@1273741c
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$1RefurbishCheckinResourceTask@59cbe3ba
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$1RefurbishCheckinResourceTask@58d3f664
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$1RefurbishCheckinResourceTask@43d54ccb
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StmtAcquireTask@68a4c637
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$1RefurbishCheckinResourceTask@19d17a8d
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StmtAcquireTask@7c4cc39
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StmtAcquireTask@93bb62b
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StmtAcquireTask@2f34c5c9
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StmtAcquireTask@31a52755
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StmtAcquireTask@51b956e9
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StmtAcquireTask@5ef904e9
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StmtAcquireTask@2eb18db5
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StmtAcquireTask@ace7e06
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StmtAcquireTask@7ab3c174
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StmtAcquireTask@2f61e59b
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StmtAcquireTask@44293b6a
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StmtAcquireTask@6efbcf1b
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StmtAcquireTask@55da2e89
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StmtAcquireTask@67255067
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StmtAcquireTask@42c1cf18
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StmtAcquireTask@420352e5
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StmtAcquireTask@68375a3e
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StmtAcquireTask@a05d1e6
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StmtAcquireTask@417582e
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StmtAcquireTask@189e361b
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StmtAcquireTask@3af2333d
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StmtAcquireTask@73020806
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StmtAcquireTask@a5cfce7
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StmtAcquireTask@5edfa701
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StmtAcquireTask@2d4d6350
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StmtAcquireTask@33b3306c
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StmtAcquireTask@39301cf8
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StmtAcquireTask@5bdfb1d
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StmtAcquireTask@7bb12fdc
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StmtAcquireTask@2dbd53f5
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StmtAcquireTask@68d31148
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StmtAcquireTask@7913c3bb
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StmtAcquireTask@976817
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StmtAcquireTask@5432be4e
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StmtAcquireTask@4f6c1e11
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StmtAcquireTask@432a16d3
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StmtAcquireTask@409918
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StmtAcquireTask@1102f6c9
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StmtAcquireTask@59980ed8
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StmtAcquireTask@df6b4dc
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StmtAcquireTask@3fdbdead
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StmtAcquireTask@7bf8509b
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StmtAcquireTask@6b742fb2
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StmtAcquireTask@18e7863b
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StmtAcquireTask@81d9843
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StmtAcquireTask@4ef75ade
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StmtAcquireTask@516ecd52
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StmtAcquireTask@4169ec42
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StmtAcquireTask@1116029b
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$1StmtAcquireTask@3c0516e0
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AsyncTestIdleResourceTask@7220eae8
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AsyncTestIdleResourceTask@4f1e5fe1
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AsyncTestIdleResourceTask@5328d55b
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AsyncTestIdleResourceTask@1dcf7404
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AsyncTestIdleResourceTask@1ec9c1e6
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AsyncTestIdleResourceTask@4fd8f2d4
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AsyncTestIdleResourceTask@2c2e6540
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AsyncTestIdleResourceTask@19f96369
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AsyncTestIdleResourceTask@43ed8fd1
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AsyncTestIdleResourceTask@217d052e
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AsyncTestIdleResourceTask@16df202f
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AsyncTestIdleResourceTask@12b9f964
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AsyncTestIdleResourceTask@6fa41dd6
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AsyncTestIdleResourceTask@7fa305dc
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AsyncTestIdleResourceTask@27d5effb
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AsyncTestIdleResourceTask@4e7e5c2b
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AsyncTestIdleResourceTask@49d5334f
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AsyncTestIdleResourceTask@4c1bad67
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AsyncTestIdleResourceTask@2d156c3a
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AsyncTestIdleResourceTask@59746af5
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AsyncTestIdleResourceTask@6a1a28b4
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AsyncTestIdleResourceTask@5b6677d7
        com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AsyncTestIdleResourceTask@2445f322
Pool thread stack traces:
    Thread[C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1bqoobh9fc5bldvr10ww5|13e9d0cc]-HelperThread-#11,5,main]
        com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1380)
        com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:179)
        com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.closePreparedHandle(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:148)
        com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.closeInternal(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:175)
        com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.close(SQLServerStatement.java:595)
        com.mchange.v1.db.sql.StatementUtils.attemptClose(StatementUtils.java:53)
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$StatementDestructionManager$1UncheckedStatementCloseTask.run(GooGooStatementCache.java:938)
        com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:648)
    Thread[C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1bqoobh9fc5bldvr10ww5|13e9d0cc]-HelperThread-#3,5,main]
        com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1380)
        com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:179)
        com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.closePreparedHandle(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:148)
        com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.closeInternal(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:175)
        com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.close(SQLServerStatement.java:595)
        com.mchange.v1.db.sql.StatementUtils.attemptClose(StatementUtils.java:53)
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$StatementDestructionManager$1UncheckedStatementCloseTask.run(GooGooStatementCache.java:938)
        com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:648)
    Thread[C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1bqoobh9fc5bldvr10ww5|13e9d0cc]-HelperThread-#13,5,main]
        com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1380)
        com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:179)
        com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.closePreparedHandle(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:148)
        com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.closeInternal(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:175)
        com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.close(SQLServerStatement.java:595)
        com.mchange.v1.db.sql.StatementUtils.attemptClose(StatementUtils.java:53)
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$StatementDestructionManager$1UncheckedStatementCloseTask.run(GooGooStatementCache.java:938)
        com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:648)
    Thread[C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1bqoobh9fc5bldvr10ww5|13e9d0cc]-HelperThread-#1,5,main]
        com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1380)
        com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:179)
        com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.closePreparedHandle(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:148)
        com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.closeInternal(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:175)
        com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.close(SQLServerStatement.java:595)
        com.mchange.v1.db.sql.StatementUtils.attemptClose(StatementUtils.java:53)
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$StatementDestructionManager$1UncheckedStatementCloseTask.run(GooGooStatementCache.java:938)
        com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:648)
    Thread[C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1bqoobh9fc5bldvr10ww5|13e9d0cc]-HelperThread-#2,5,main]
        com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1380)
        com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:179)
        com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.closePreparedHandle(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:148)
        com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.closeInternal(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:175)
        com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.close(SQLServerStatement.java:595)
        com.mchange.v1.db.sql.StatementUtils.attemptClose(StatementUtils.java:53)
        com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache$StatementDestructionManager$1UncheckedStatementCloseTask.run(GooGooStatementCache.java:938)
        com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:648)
```

Our pool connection settings are these:

```
<property name="maxIdleTime" value="600" />
<property name="maxPoolSize" value="200" />
<property name="maxStatements" value="200" />
<property name="minPoolSize" value="15" />
<property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="100" />
<property name="acquireIncrement" value="3"/>
<property name="numHelperThreads" value="20"/>
```

What should we investigate on?

Comment: What do you see on the SQL server when running a sp_who command?

Comment: @Marius - I never tried to issue the sp_who command during these moments. If I issue it now I see over 100 connection lines, the majority in sleeping state. In what way this info would help me? Thanks

Comment: If your application deadlocks, it will tell you if SQL server is issuing commands which are preventing hibernate from closing the connection.

Comment: Ok, next time I will try to issue a sp_who to see if I find something strange. 
In the while, is there something that looks wrong in our configuration?
Thanks

Comment: I don't see anything peculiar in the configuration, you may want to decrease the maxIdleTime for testing. Are you able to reproduce the deadlock using a stresstest?

Comment: Ah ok thanks. Till now we didn't succeed in reproducing the issue locally. We should try harder I think.

Comment: What OS are you running your application server on? I've seen cases where a file limit (ulimit, ubuntu server) was causing connections to remain lingering.

Comment: It's Windows Server ranging from 2008 to 2012